# Getting incorrect response from elasticsearch Node.js client v7.2.0 for aggregation query

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am sending a nested aggregation query on a nested object using the Node.js client v7.2.0 for elasticsearch. While executing the query on Node.js client, i am getting all the records for that index and not the filtered result with aggregation. Executing the same query using kibana or curl provides the expected result.

Query :-

```
const client = new Client({ node: 'http://localhost:9200' });

let body = {
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
      "bool": {
          "must": [
              {
                  "nested": {
                      "path": "doc.parentKey",
                      "query": {
                          "bool": {
                              "must": [
                                  {
                                      "term": {
                                          "doc.parentKey.name.keyword": "Name1"
                                      }
                                  }
                              ]
                          }
                      }
                  }
              },
              {
                  "term": {
                      "doc.owner.keyword": "0aa7b933-eab1-4939-b4d2-38c2d0602cba"
                  }
              }
          ]
      }
  },
  "aggs": {
      "parentKey": {
          "nested": {
              "path": "doc.parentKey"
          },
          "aggs": {
              "response": {
                  "aggs": {
                      "name": {
                          "terms": {
                              "field": "doc.parentKey.name.keyword"
                          },
                          "aggs": {
                              "value": {
                                  "terms": {
                                      "field": "doc.parentKey.value.keyword"
                                  }
                              }
                          }
                      }
                  },
                  "filter": {
                      "term": {
                          "doc.parentKey.name.keyword": "Name1"
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }
}
let {body: response} = await client.search({index: 'test-index', body});
```

Expected result (Getting this from kibana and curl)

```
{
  "took" : 47,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 131,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "parentKey" : {
      "doc_count" : 10218,
      "response" : {
        "doc_count" : 131,
        "name" : {
          "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
          "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
          "buckets" : [
            {
              "key" : "Name1",
              "doc_count" : 131,
              "value" : {
                "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
                "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
                "buckets" : [
                  {
                    "key" : "Value1",
                    "doc_count" : 131
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result from Node.js client

```
{
    "body": {
        "took": 1277,
        "timed_out": false,
        "_shards": {
            "total": 1,
            "successful": 1,
            "skipped": 0,
            "failed": 0
        },
        "hits": {
            "total": {
                "value": 10000,
                "relation": "gte"
            },
            "max_score": 1,
            "hits": [
                {
                    "_index": "indexName",
                    "_type": "_doc",
                    "_id": "2f0e4524-1203-40a6-8527-aa980fc349a7[8196858]",
                    "_score": 1,
                    "_source": {
                        "doc": {
                            "owner": "059d2569-f268-417f-906b-cbed1f6fbcec",
                            "parentKey": [
                                {
                                    "value": "Value3",
                                    "name": "Name3"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "Value4",
                                    "name": "Name4"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "@version": "1",
                        "doc_as_upsert": true,
                        "@timestamp": "2019-07-31T09:29:27.644Z"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "_index": "indexName",
                    "_type": "_doc",
                    "_id": "6f5652a3-8b33-4c53-8bea-316e8ab1b8c5[8201864]",
                    "_score": 1,
                    "_source": {
                        "doc": {
                            "owner": "71a83599-1751-4fa4-896a-46b644f29a50"
                            "parentKey": [
                                {
                                    "value": "Value1",
                                    "name": "Name1"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "Value2",
                                    "name": "Name2"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "@version": "1",
                        "doc_as_upsert": true,
                        "@timestamp": "2019-07-31T09:29:33.795Z"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
        "content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        "date": "Thu, 08 Aug 2019 13:27:15 GMT",
        "server": "nginx/1.12.2",
        "content-length": "113899",
        "connection": "keep-alive"
    },
    "warnings": null,
    "meta": {
        "context": null,
        "request": {
            "params": {
                "method": "GET",
                "path": "/indexName/_search",
                "body": "",
                "querystring": "",
                "headers": {
                    "User-Agent": "elasticsearch-js/7.3.0 (linux 3.10.0-862.9.1.el7.x86_64-x64; Node.js v8.9.4)",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "Content-Length": "0"
                },
                "timeout": 30000
            },
            "options": {
                "size": 0,
                "aggs": {
                    "parentKey": {
                        "nested": {
                            "path": "doc.parentKey"
                        },
                        "aggs": {
                            "response": {
                                "aggs": {
                                    "name": {
                                        "terms": {
                                            "field": "doc.parentKey.name.keyword"
                                        },
                                        "aggs": {
                                            "value": {
                                                "terms": {
                                                    "field": "doc.parentKey.value.keyword"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "filter": {
                                    "term": {
                                        "doc.parentKey.name.keyword": "63bb04a3eb41417e8d0e61e074293581"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "warnings": null
            },
            "id": 1
        },
        "name": "elasticsearch-js",
        "connection": {
            "url": "http://elasticsearch",
            "id": "http://elasticsearch",
            "headers": {},
            "deadCount": 0,
            "resurrectTimeout": 0,
            "_openRequests": 0,
            "status": "alive",
            "roles": {
                "master": true,
                "data": true,
                "ingest": true,
                "ml": false
            }
        },
        "attempts": 0,
        "aborted": false
    }
}
```

The response from Node.js client is truncated(the response consisted of 10 objects inside hits.hits array which we would also get by running match_all for this index)

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the node.js code that you're using?

Comment: I've updated the question. Please check now.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're missing a key in your `search` call:

```
let {body: response} = await client.search({index: 'test-index', body: body});
                                                                   ^
                                                                   |
                                                            add the body key
```

Comment: It'll work even without it. With Object property shorthand in ES6, {body: body} can simply be passed like {body}.